# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when using em.createQuery

Tags: sql, xml, jakarta-ee, sax

So I'm parsing an Xml file with Sax and I want to find out if an entity already exists in my database. I'm using the createQuery part of my code @endElement:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU");
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();  
........
    empExisists = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Employee s WHERE s.userName=:userName", Employee.class). setParameter("userName", emp.getUserName()).getSingleResult();
```

I have already used this code somewhere else in my application and it worked fine.

Now something very strange happens, I'm getting an SQLIntegrityConstraintException because there is a primary key violation.

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Die Anweisung wurde abgebrochen, weil sie in einer für 'EMPLOYEE' definierten Vorgabe für einen eindeutigen oder Primärschlüssel bzw. für einen von 'SQL120805145505950' bezeichneten eindeutigen Index zu einem duplizierten Schlüsselwert geführt hätte.
```

I really have no clue why this exception appears because I'm not tying to persist any entity here. My persist part is located at endDocument where I catch all ConstraintViolationExceptions.

Comment: emp is a temporary object with all important data extracted from the xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that java allways calls em.flush()  before it tries to do em.createQuery to guarantee that all data is stored in the database.

I still dont know excactly why this error accours because my entity manger shouldnt cotain any EMPLOYEE Objects which are goning to be persisted before em.createQuery is called.

Im using now a workaround with em.clear() right before em.createQuery where the exception occurred. Because of that i´m now allways using em.fush() right after i used em.persist().

I think its not a very good solution for this problem so if there are better solutions then please let me know